# KMS clients still try to talk to MS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, kms

I've found that Windows KMS clients (2012R2 specifically but may be others) try to talk to MS servers during activation.  My understanding was that this should be entirely local.

`slmgr /ipk GGWHX-.....-.....-.....-DJ6PQ
slmgr /skms 10.10.10.10:1688
slmgr /ato`

Our servers have very limited access outside our network I've found that the above produces a 0x80072ee2 error unless a proxy server is specified.  This has caught me out as I often configure the proxy settings soon after building servers.  On this particular server, it is not allowed to have a proxy configured.

Any ideas how to get 2012R2 to activate against an internal KMS server without access to MS via the Internet?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key you've started to list there does not appear to be a KMS client key. You should not install a key on the client if it is going to be KMS activated. The OS image from Microsoft ships with the client KMS key pre-installed - it is the same for every computer of that OS on the planet.

If you've already changed some clients from the default, you can change them back using the keys here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612867(v=ws.11).aspx

For reference, the KMS client key for 2012 R2 Datacenter is `W3GGN-FT8W3-Y4M27-J84CP-Q3VJ9` And the Standard edition key is: `D2N9P-3P6X9-2R39C-7RTCD-MDVJX`

Comment: Un-believable.... Yep, that seems to have done it.